# DHCP not issuing out IP addresses

Tags: wireless-networking, command-line, router, ip, dhcp

DHCP on my network is no longer issuing out IP addresses. Every new device must be manually configured to connect to the network. After executing `show ip dhcp binding`, i noticed that all the ip addresses were assigned (with infinite leases). Executing `show ip dhcp pool` gives:

```
 Utilization mark (high/low)    : 100 / 0
 Subnet size (first/next)       : 0 / 0 
 Total addresses                : 254
 Leased addresses               : 183
 Pending event                  : none
 1 subnet is currently in the pool :
 Current index        IP address range                    Leased addresses
 0.0.0.0              192.168.1.1      - 192.168.1.254     183
```

and running `show run` gives:

```
Current configuration : 1971 bytes
!
version 15.2
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname myhost
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
!
ip cef
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.60
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.109 192.168.1.116
```

My questions are:

1. Will changing the leases on the already assigned IPs from infinite to say a month solve the issue?
2. How do i increase my DHCP pool? Perhaps to give IPs in the form `192.168.0.x`? . As shown above the gateway is `192.168.1.1` with subnet `255.255.255.0`

The router in use is a cisco 1941 router. Don’t have much experience with cisco CLI, i would appreciate the commands to execute (2) above.

Thank you.

Comment: Re: `Will changing the leases on the already assigned IPs from infinite to say a month solve the issue?`  It depends on how often you connect new devices. If you have more than a few hundred per month then you will still run out.  (Normal leases in places where I worked are up to 3 days, allowing the same IP to be kept over a weekend. I Never saw any place with infinite lease time.

Comment: okay thanks got it. Will adjust that. Any ideas on number 2?

Comment: No. Though some googling shows that `if you need to extend the current DHCP pool range, remove the current pool of addresses and specify the new range of IP addresses under the DHCP pool`. (source: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/dynamic-address-allocation-resolution/27470-100.html).

Comment: Also possibly useful as a **temporarily** workaround: `clear ip dhcp binding *` Do this outside business hours. Wiping all leases allowing some spare time. But unless the lease time is limited, or no/fewer new devices are introduced, or you get bigger pool than there are devices you will run out again in due time.

Comment: okay that makes sense. I'm actually torn on whether to adjust the current pool, changing the mask from `255.255.255.0` to `255.255.252.0` to get up to 1022 addresses (not sure about the implications of this) or just creating a new pool entirely.

Comment: this is not a good idea of merging your subnets and creating a bigger one. better make your lease time at 6-8 hour, and don't worry DHCP has a mechanism that renew connected host leases at 75% of expiring time, so you can make the lease time even on 2h

Comment: That will give you a bigger broadcast domain. If there are actually a lot of computers/devices/phones on that domain then overhead will increase.  This might not be a problem for a modern system but you might want to think about subnetting. And I would still limit the lease to a limited time unless you want to keep a record of every single device. (Not that that is worth much since changing the MAC is trivial).

Comment: @Hennes ok understood. How much downtime should i expect after executing `clear ip dhcp binding *`?.

Comment: @emirjonb ok. So you're saying merging subnets is quite inefficient? So what do i do about running out of IPs.

Comment: 1)Maybe we should move to Superusers chat room (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access), but that requires 20 reputation to use.
2) Merging subnets (Cisco-ish speak) or just using a larger subnet (rest of the world) is not a problem with a few devices. But actively using a lot more devices at the same time is not a good idea due to the broadcast domain.

Best to think of it as a room. If someone shouts in the room then everyone will hear it. Increasing the subnet is making a larger room. A large room with many shouts (broadcast) increases overhead.

Comment: @Hennes Okay. A bit confused on what step to take now. I really do need to increase the pool. It's a medium-sized hotel so i don't foresee too many devices but at the same i don't want to slow down the network at all. Imagine having to manually configure each guest's device. Its so tiring. Please advice me on what to do.

Comment: First decide an what to do? How many active devices do you have? (E.g. 150 users with 150 laptops. But with 100 of those in the office on an average day: -> Pool size >100 needed. But probably not 150 since not everyone will be in.). Next decide on a lease time. Most client will use that lease until half the time is up, then ask for renewal. This means that even if you set the lease to 4 hours that it can be used all day long without disturbing anyone. (but next morning the pool would be empty since the laptops were turned off at night).  No more problems.

Comment: If you want laptops  to have a semi permanent address then increase the lease time. E.g. to a day, 3 days, a week... but not forever because that way any old device (e.g. a broken and replaced laptop, or a phone with WiFi from a customer which tried to connect just once on a single day) will keep clogging your resources.

Comment: Once you decided on that you can work toward the chosen solution. And that can be a clear cut command which should be posted an an answer (possibly with some of the explanations as to why from these comment included). Afterwards we can clean these comments to leave a nice clean post and a clean answer.

Comment: Alright. I think i will just leave the pool the way it is, reduce the lease time to 4hours and see  how things work out.

Comment: @Hennes i executed `clear ip dhcp binding` and reduced the lease time to 4hours and it started giving out IPs again. I'll monitor the network for a while to see how things pan out. Thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: Can you post that as your own answer (including the commands used to reduce the lease time to 4 hours). That way it can help future visitors of this site.  After that we can remove our comments to clean up this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since,increasing the DHCP pool by merging subnets could increase overhead and slow down the network, 
what i did was to first of all clear all ip bindings on the server. (this is because the leases on IPs were infinite, thus all old devices were clogging resources). Then i reduced the changed the lease period to 4hours and dhcp began issuing addresses again.

To clear ip bindings:

```
enable                        //enter privileged exec mode
clear ip dhcp binding *      //use this command in privileged EXEC mode
```

To change the lease period to four hours:

```
configure terminal               //enter global config mode
ip dhcp pool mypoolname         //enter existing dhcp pool
lease 0 4 0                    //this does the changing of the lease period
end                           //exit dhcp config
```

Comment: Agreed, clearing bindings may make some IP addresses available again.

Answer (score 3):

183 leased + 59+7 reserved = 249. Your IP address pool is full.
If the addresses lower than 192.168.1.60 are not used, try to reallocate reserved to pool:

```
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.10
```

That will give you 50 extra IP addresses to assign via DHCP.

Note that you only should do this if the IP addresses between 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.60 are not in use (not configured statically anywhere in the network).

Comment: Thanks this is also another solution. Combining both solutions might be a good idea.